# VS 2017 15.9.11 cannot select target framework for .net core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a new installation for VS 2017 with version 15.9.11, but after that I realized my ASP.NET Core projects cannot target to .NET 2.2, even thought .NET SDK 2.2.205 was installed

I tried unchecking the option 'Use previews of the .NET Core SDK' in the Options > Projects and Solutions, but it was no help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET SDK 2.2.202 cannot be displayed in the target framework list of VS 2017 15.9.11, but I found a workaround with additional installation for .NET [SDK 2.2.105](https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/8148cce0-196d-4634-86df-f3d4550b1a75/89ed68d0ecf6b1c62cc7b0d129fdf600/dotnet-sdk-2.2.105-win-x64.exe) it should work.

[image]